# how to add specific column from html website to list box

Tags: html, multithreading, listbox, filenames, indexof

so i want to display in the list box when i click 'Button1' only the file names of the files in this directory of my website http://prntscr.com/i8doj3 . i want all them files names in the list box. this is the rubbish code i came up with it only shows the whole of the html source code.

```
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim page As String = client.DownloadString("http://comboxy.com/configsa/")

    ListBox1.Items.Add(page)
```

Comment: This looks like Visual Basic. Is that correct? Also, I'm not sure how `multithreading` or `indexof` tie into this...

Comment: Yes this is Visual Basic. Also I couldn’t think of key words that were already created for the topic of this.